# Proving normality of a subset from its generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Exercise 3.26 in Dummit and Foote reads:

> Let $N = \langle S\rangle$ for some subset $S$ of $G$. Prove that $N \trianglelefteq G$ if $ gSg^{-1} \subseteq N$  for all $g \in G$.

If $S$ is a finite set, I presume the proof is straightforward. Suppose $ gSg^{-1} \subseteq N$  for all $g \in G$. Any element of $N$ can be written as a product of elements of $S$. The properties of conjugation therefore make that the conjugate of an element of $N$ is a product of conjugates of elements of $S$. Since the latter by the assumption are all in $N$, conjugation will be closed in $N$.

I have two questions, however. First, how to go about an infinite $S$? An element of $N$ could be a product with infinitely many factors, for which the properties of conjugation have not been proven.

Second, I would think that the question might have read:

> "Prove that $N \trianglelefteq G$ if and only if $ gSg^{-1} \subseteq N$  for all $g \in G$."

Indeed, if $N \trianglelefteq G$, since $S \subseteq N$, $gSg^{-1} \subseteq N$  for all $g \in G$, proving the reverse implication.

Did I make a mistake here? (I am suspicious because it is my impression that it is not very like. D&F not to make the most comprehensive statements.)

Comment: How can an element of $N$ be the product of an infinite number of factors?  How is that even defined?  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N=\langle S\rangle$ means by definition that every element in $N$ can be written as a *finite* product of elements in $S$. Even if $S$ is infinite, only finite products are involved.

The converse direction also holds, you did not make a mistake. But the authors did not mention it because it is not so interesting, since it is a rather trivial statement.